# How to play fullscreen by default in android for embedded Video player using react-native-webview?

Tags: android, fullscreen, video-player, react-native-webview, embedded-video

I've been using the `react-native-webview` for playing Youtube and Vimeo playbacks on my mobile app. In iOS it works fine but in android it behaves a bit different. I want to make my android to play on fullscreen when pressed on play. iOs it's default behaviour is correct.

adding `fs` in the source uri didn't worked for me